# how to make withCount conditional in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `users` model and a `comments` relationship now I want to select the `users` with more than 100 `comments` for this I am doing like below :

```
$users = User::withCount('comments')->having('comments_count','>','100')->paginate(10);
return $users;
```

but I got below error while code is been executed:

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "comments_count" does not exist LINE 1:
```

now my question is that how can I get the users more than 100 comments or any other relationship like `likes` thanks

Comment: having is used when you have an alias of the column. you need to use `where` clause instead of `having`

Comment: use `simplePaginate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a closure to the withCount() method, but that will only affect which rows get counted.
So you cannot do that.

You can use the has() method.

```
$users = User::has('comments', '>', 100)->withCount('comments')->paginate(10);
```